# Having prblem in setting height of fb:fan

Tags: facebook

I want to set the height of page_stream_short but the css defaults to 250px;
Is it possible to set the height:
This is what iam doing:

> .fan_box .page_stream_short { position:relative; height:525px
>   !important;
>
> }

Guide me, what am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

if you are using IE8 to view, you may be running into this problem: http://boardreader.com/thread/IE8_ignores_some_css_styles_in_fan_box_6cvuuX24v6.html